# select latest version of document from document library

Tags: document-library, document, word

i am converting word document in library to html document using event receiver it is working fine. but when i update the document and upload it.Event receiver code convert older document to html not my latest document .i am using SharePoint2010.

Comment: Can you post some code from your Event receiver

Comment: Please post the answer below and mark it as correct to close the Question.. If you think answer won't help anyone, just delete the Question.. :)